# Get un updated migrations name in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I'm working on `Code First` `MVC project` with `C#`.
I have many migrations that some of them is not updated in data base.
I want update migration dynamically. so I need get last updated migration in data base and my un updated migration in source code in visual studio.
How to I can get my un updated migration name in my source code?

> Updated

```
var myUnUpdatedMigrationFromMigrationFolder = ?????;
if(myLastUpdatedMigration != myUnUpdatedMigrationFromMigrationFolder)
{
      var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Model.Migrations.Configuration());
      migrator.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;` to:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : 
      DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext>
{
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}

protected override void Seed(ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext context)
{
    //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

    //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
    //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
    //
    //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
    //      p => p.FullName,
    //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
    //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
    //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
    //    );
    //
}
}
```

Comment: tanks for your answer.
I did this configs. now I need get my recent un updated migrations.
this code is not my answer!